# Does there exist Convolution theorem for Inverse Fourier map?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

The Fourier transform of convolution is: $F (f \ast g)= F (f)  \cdot F(g)$, where $F$ represents Fourier map. I wonder if there exists similar statement for inverse Fourier map i.e. does it hold that $F ^{-1}(f \ast g)= F^{-1} (f)  \cdot F^{-1}(g)$. I haven't found anywhere such statement (so i think that is not true), but I would like to be sure that it doesn't holds. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There is a similar statement for the inverse Fourier transform but it depends on your definition of the Fourier transform. There are several conventions available.

Comment: Could you please write that statement? I use the following definitions: $ \hat{f}(t)= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-i t x} dx$ and $ f(x)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}(t) e^{i t x} dt$.

Comment: What part of the proof for $F$ is not clear for $F^{-1}$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your convention, we have $F^{-1}(f)(x) = {1\over 2\pi}F(f)(-x)$. As a result,
$$
F^{-1}(f*g)(x) = {1 \over 2\pi} F(f*g)(-x)
= {1 \over 2\pi}\ F(f)(-x)\ F(g)(-x)
=  2\pi\ F^{-1}(f)(x)\ F^{-1}(g)(x).
$$

We end up with
$$
F^{-1}(f*g) = 2\pi\  F^{-1}(f)\ F^{-1}(g).
$$